# ASP.Net MVC Hidden field not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have maybe a strange requirement, but I thought implementing it would be easy.

I pass a List<> into a View. Within the view, I 'foreach' though the list, and build a Table. Within the table, I need to add hidden fields, so that I can get the values back on the post.

However, I am finding that when I use Html.Hidden, the field isn't rendered. In the view source, there is no mention of the fields...

```
        <table width="600">
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <td>
                Category
            </td>
            <td>
                Sub Category
            </td>
            <td>
                Amount
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% 
            if (Model.TransactionSplitLines != null)
            {
                foreach (var line in Model.TransactionSplitLines)
                {%>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=line.Category%>                
                <%=Html.Hidden("CategoryId", line.CategoryId.ToString()) %>

            </td>
            <td>
                <%=line.SubCategory%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=line.Amount%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        } %>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

When I am then hoping to do is have an array of CategoryId, which I can read within the controller on the Action event.

Comment: Can you check if Model.TransactionSplitLines.Length>0? Also do you see line.Category rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use an editor template for this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <table width="600">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headerRow">
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Sub Category</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.TransactionSplitLines) %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
<% } %>
```

and then have a corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TransactionSplitLine.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Model.TransactionSplitLine>" %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Category) %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CategoryId) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SubCategory) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Amount) %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now not only that your view are much more readable but editor templates will take care of generating proper names for your hidden fields so that you can bind your model back:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model)
{
    // TODO: model.TransactionSplitLines should be properly bound 
    // at least the CategoryId property because it's the only one 
    // you are sending in the post
    ...
}
```

where SomeViewModel looks like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel 
{
    public IEnumerable<TransactionSplitLine> TransactionSplitLines { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class TransactionSplitLine
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to try this. I have my TransactionSplitLines as a LIST<> as opposed to IEnumerable. Is this OK, or must it be IENumerable to work?

Comment: @cdotlister, it is good practice to always use the class/interface which is highest in the hierarchy. So for example if you are only going to enumerate which seems to be the case use `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: My issue is I need to add items -  foreach (var c in model.CategoryIds)
                {
                    reply.TransactionSplitLines.Add(new TransactionSplitLine
                                                        {Amount = "100", Category = "Test", SubCategory = "Test More", CategoryId=int.Parse(c)});
                }

Comment: @cdotlister, this is the responsibility of the controller and not the view. If you need to add items dynamically using javascript that's another thing: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: Sorry Darin - I wasn't clear - thanks for your patience so far... That code is in the controller. Basically, I (at the moment) pass in a List<>, and build a table based on the list. In the form, the user selects a new Category, SubCategory and amount, and clicks an 'Add' button. The form goes back to the controller, and the idea was that I add the form values to the List<>, and then return the view with the form values added to the Table. This can be done multiple times, so each time, the form values are added to the List<> (And therefore, the table).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would be generating multiple fields with the same ID (CategoryID), have you tried not using the Html.Helper and simply replacing it with this:

```
<input type='hidden' value='<%= line.CategoryId.ToString()%>' />
```

However - if you need to grab them by some type of ID - you could add a class inside there and use jQuery to pull all of your values:

```
<input class='CategoryId' type='hidden' value='<%=line.CategoryId.ToString()%>'/>
```

Then just use a `$('.CategoryId').each()` function to populate your list and POST it to your controller.