# Postback Data is not retained

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, postback

I just got out of ASP.NET Web Forms and is now an MVC newbie.
I have read that MVC does not manage ViewState unlike ASP.NET Web Forms. I was wondering how you can achieve data persistence.

I have this simple form with a strongly-typed model:

```
class MyModel
{
    public string TextboxData { get; set; }
    public string HiddenData { get; set; }
}
```

With the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextboxData)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HiddenData)
}
```

My controller is a simple one. It simply processes the data in the model and passes it back to the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PerformAction(MyModel mv)
{
    mv.DoSomething();
    return View(mv);        
}
```

Since the controller just reuses the Model, am I correct to assume that all entered data via the previous submit will be retained on the next refresh?

Actually, the one for TextboxData was retained (after postback, the textbox still contains the entered data) but the one for HiddenData was not retained. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is the mv.HiddenData variable in the controller filled with the data when you do a postback? If not, the data will of course not be sent to the view. And yes, you are correct that when the mv contains content for the two properties, they should show up in the view. I presume you enter the data for the hidden field in the HttpGet (since you can not enter it in the hidden field in the form..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are doing correct stuff, it should send hidden text data as well when posted back to server.

Seems Id for hidden field is duplicated or not valid. Please refer

[Razor MVC model is losing data on Save action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435809/razor-mvc-model-is-losing-data-on-save-action)

[ASP.Net MVC Hidden field not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021116/asp-net-mvc-hidden-field-not-working-as-expected)

Hope these posts may resolve your issue.

Comment: It seems another third-party plugin was using the same ID I was using, so the browser got confused. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

If inside the `mv.DoSomething();` you modify the value of either the `TextboxData` or `HiddenData` properties, those changes won't get reflected when you render the view. The reason for that is because HTML helpers such as `TextBoxFor` and `HiddenFor` are first looking inside the ModelState when binding and then in the model. This is by design.

So if you need to modify the originally posted values inside a POST action you need to remove them from the ModelState first:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PerformAction(MyModel mv)
{
    // we intend to modify the values => we must remove them from ModelState
    // or the HTML helpers will reuse the old values
    ModelState.Remove("TextboxData");
    ModelState.Remove("HiddenData");

    mv.TextboxData = "some new value";
    mv.HiddenData = "some new hidden value";

    return View(mv);        
}
```

Comment: I did not actually modify the postback values in DoSomething. But at least I now know if you need to remove those values in MOdelState. Thanks

Comment: +1 This info is very useful, thank for enlightening us.

Answer (score 1):

On a POST your model is automagically filled in.

See an explanation of how model binding works on [this dotnetslackers article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx)

Now to your problem - Looking at the code posted in the question, it looks like you are doing it right. To figure out the problem here is what you should do
 1. View source of your page.
 2. Check if the hidden field is rendered with a value (whatever value you are expecting)

If the hidden field rendered is not set with the value you are expecting to see, it probably means that on the get, when the model was created, "m.HiddenData" was not set with the proper values.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I got it. It seems another element was named the same ID I was using. The browser was confused I guess.